# How to accept PascalCase instead of camelCase in post request body nodes using Spring Boot Framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

Im am developing a REST API using Spring Framework. I have a post controller set up:

```
@PostMapping(path="/v2/document", consumes= {"application/xml","application/json"}, produces={"application/xml","application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> postDocument(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody Template template) throws Exception
```

It takes in a Template object:
public class Template{

```
@XmlElement(name = "Callback")  
private String Callback;

@XmlElement(name = "OutputFormat")  
private String OutputFormat;

@XmlElement(name = "Data")  
private byte[] Data;

@XmlElement(name = "ConnectionString")  
private String ConnectionString;
    
@XmlElement(name = "Format")    
private String Format;

@XmlElementWrapper(name="Properties")
@XmlElement(name = "Property")
private Property[] Properties;
```

Right now this is the request body that works:

```
    <Template>
    <connectionString>ConString</connectionString>
    <outputFormat>pdf</outputFormat>
     <datasources>
        <datasource>
                <connectionString>ConString</connectionString>
        </datasource>
    </datasources>
</Template>
```

Where the outer tags are the proper PascalCase format , but the inner tags have to be camelCase. This is how I want the body to look:

```
<Template>
    <ConnectionString>ConString</ConnectionString>
    <OutputFormat>pdf</OutputFormat>
     <Datasources>
        <Datasource>
                <ConnectionString>ConString</ConnectionString>
        </Datasource>
    </Datasources>
</Template>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Template")
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Template{
```

And now it works the way I want it.

Answer (score 0):

This is *Deprecated* now, you have to use `PropertyNamingStrategies` instead of `PropertyNamingStrategy`.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="Template")
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Template{
```